# MySql 8 Could not load JDBC driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, driver, mysql-connector, jackrabbit

*I am a Spring MVC beginner using Tomcat 7.0.79 with Eclipse to run a spring application. I receive the following error at run time.

```
ERROR  info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager 26.09.2019 11:11:38 -- org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Could not load JDBC driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Mysql is 8 versione
But mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar already exists in the project as a Maven dependency
below is the summary of my jackrabbit config:

```
<DataSources>
        <DataSource name="author">
            <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <param name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
            <param name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_salesportal_author?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;useSSL=false" />
            <param name="user" value="****" />
            <param name="password" value="****" />

            <param name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        </DataSource>


<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="dataSourceName" value="author" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024" />
        <param name="maxConnections" value="100" />
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true" />
        <param name="tablePrefix" value="" />
    </DataStore>
```

Comment: is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver actually in mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar ??

Comment: What's the rest of the stacktrace? You've shown "Could not load", but the rest of the stacktrace answers "why it could not load".

Comment: Remove the `.cj` part. It's obsolete.

Comment: @user207421 It is actually the reverse, the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is the **new** driver name (introduced in MySQL Connector/J 8 (technically in version 6, but that was rebranded to 8 before GA), and `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` has been deprecated.

Comment: The error could mean that the driver is not actually on the classpath when your application is run (or possibly on the wrong classpath).